# text to list of tuples

Tags: python, data-science, search-engine

I have a text dataset. the content of the text is looks like as follows.

```
.I 1\n.T\nPreliminary Report-International Algebraic Language\n.B\nCACM December,
 .I 2\n.T\nExtraction of Roots by,5\t3\n .I 3\n.T\nTechniquI 4\n.T\nGlossary of Computer
```

this is the description of the dataset

.I 1, I.2, .I 3 -> are the document id and the rest of the text is the content of the document.
the task is: to create a list of tuples-> [(doc_id, content)]. Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FILENAME = "your filename"
f = open(FILENAME)
lst = []
lines = f.read().splitlines()
for i in range(0,len(lines),3):
    lst.append((lines[i],lines[i+1]))
```

`print(lst)`

->>>[('.i 1', 'lipsum lipsum lipsum lipsum B. lipsum lipsum '), ('.i 2', 'lipsum lipsum '), ('.i 3', 'lipsum  lipsum  lipsum lipsum')]

Comment: the code seems to work fine however  when it is provided with different data set like this one: .I 1
.T
Preliminary Report-International Algebraic Language
.B
CACM December, 1958
.A
Perlis, A. J.
Samelson,K.
.N .I 2
.T
Extraction of Roots by Repeated Subtractions for Digital Computers
.B
CACM December, 1958
.A
Sugai, I. where .i 1 and .i 2 are the document id and the rest is the content. the returned value was [('.I 1', '.T'), ('.B', 'CACM December, 1958')] many tuples more than needed in a list.

Comment: This code expects first line to be key, next line to be value. Next line to be blank. If the file is not like that. You will receive different output. Your example is not clear in comment section due to absence of line break. You may edit the question and put it there

Comment: Hi @Baban, i have updated the exact data